# Increase width of paralists, esp. in xltabular

Tags: paralist, xltabular

The first part of the question -- how to increase the width of a list -- seems relatively easy, though I couldn't find the answer in `paralist.sty`. The second part, whether it behaves differently in `xltabular` is not so clear, so I add examples for `compactitem`, `compactenum` and `asparaenum`. Just in case...

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\RequirePackage{hyphsubst}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,landscape,DIV=10]{scrartcl}
\recalctypearea
\PreventPackageFromLoading{fixltx2e}
\PassOptionsToPackage{activate={true,nocompatibility},verbose=silent,%
                      expansion=true,protrusion=true,final}{microtype}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,calc}
\usepackage[defblank]{paralist}
\usepackage{mathtools,letltxmacro,luatextra}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{1\linewidth}{@{}>{\hsize=.15\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.4\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.45\hsize}X@{}}
  Seite & Froschkönig & Kommentar \\\toprule
  \endfirsthead
  Seite & Froschkönig & Kommentar \\\toprule
  \endhead
        & & Fortsetzung...
  \endfoot
  \endlastfoot
       1 & In den alten Zeiten, wo das Wünschen noch geholfen hat,
           lebte ein König, dessen Töchter waren alle schön; aber die
           jüngste war so schön, daß die Sonne selber, die doch so
           vieles gesehen hat, sich verwunderte, sooft sie ihr ins
           Gesicht schien. 
            & Nahe bei dem Schlosse des Königs lag ein großer dunkler 
              Wald, und in dem Walde unter einer alten Linde war ein 
              Brunnen; wenn nun der Tag recht heiß war, so ging das 
              Königskind hinaus in den Wald und setzte sich an den Rand 
              des kühlen Brunnens - und wenn sie Langeweile hatte, so 
              nahm sie eine goldene Kugel, warf sie in die Höhe und fing 
              sie wieder; und das war ihr liebstes Spielwerk. \\
       1 &
           \begin{compactenum}
           \item Nun trug es sich einmal zu, daß die goldene Kugel der
             Königstochter nicht in ihr Händchen fiel,
           \item das sie in die Höhe gehalten hatte, sondern vorbei
             auf die Erde schlug und geradezu ins Wasser hineinrollte.
           \item Die Königstochter folgte ihr mit den Augen nach, 
           \item aber die Kugel verschwand, und der Brunnen war tief,
             so tief, daß man keinen Grund sah.
           \end{compactenum}
              &  Da fing sie an zu weinen und weinte immer lauter und 
                 konnte sich gar nicht trösten. Und wie sie so klagte, 
                 rief ihr jemand zu:

                 "`Was hast du vor, Königstochter, du schreist ja, daß 
                   sich ein Stein erbarmen möchte."' \\
       2--3 & Sie sah sich um, woher die Stimme käme, da erblickte sie
              einen Frosch, der seinen dicken, häßlichen Kopf aus dem
              Wasser streckte. "`Ach, du bist's, alter
              Wasserpatscher,"' sagte sie, "`ich weine über meine
              goldene Kugel, die mir in den Brunnen hinabgefallen
              ist."'
                  & "`Sei still und weine nicht,"' antwortete der Frosch, 
                    "`ich kann wohl Rat schaffen, aber was gibst du mir, 
                    wenn ich dein Spielwerk wieder heraufhole?"' -- "`Was 
                    du haben willst, lieber Frosch,"' sagte sie; "`meine 
                    Kleider, meine Perlen und Edelsteine, auch noch die goldene 
                    Krone, die ich trage."' Der Frosch antwortete: "`Deine 
                    Kleider, deine Perlen und Edelsteine und deine goldene Krone, die 
                    mag ich nicht: aber wenn du mich liebhaben willst, und ich soll 
                    dein Geselle und Spielkamerad sein, an deinem Tischlein neben 
                    dir sitzen, von deinem goldenen Tellerlein essen, aus deinem 
                    Becherlein trinken, in deinem Bettlein schlafen: wenn du mir 
                    das versprichst, so will ich hinuntersteigen und dir die 
                    goldene Kugel wieder heraufholen."' \\
     3 &
         \begin{compactitem}
         \item "`Ach ja,"' sagte sie, "`ich verspreche dir alles, was
           du willst, wenn du mir nur die Kugel wieder bringst."'
         \item Sie dachte aber: Was der einfältige Frosch schwätzt!
           Der sitzt im Wasser bei seinesgleichen und quakt und kann
           keines Menschen Geselle sein.
         \item Der Frosch, als er die Zusage erhalten hatte, tauchte
           seinen Kopf unter, sank hinab, und über ein Weilchen kam er
           wieder heraufgerudert, hatte die Kugel im Maul und warf sie
           ins Gras. 
         \end{compactitem}
              &
                \begin{asparaenum}
                \item  Die Königstochter war voll Freude, als sie ihr 
                       schönes Spielwerk wieder erblickte, hob es auf und 
                       sprang damit fort.
                \item "`Warte, warte,"' rief der Frosch, "`nimm mich mit, 
                      ich kann nicht so laufen wie du!"' Aber was half es 
                      ihm, daß er ihr sein Quak, Quak so laut nachschrie, als 
                      er konnte!
                \item Sie hörte nicht darauf, eilte nach Hause und hatte bald 
                      den armen Frosch vergessen, der wieder in seinen Brunnen 
                      hinabsteigen mußte.
                \end{asparaenum}

\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you already try with `\begin{xltabular}{1\linewidth}{@{}lXX@{}}`? At least in the case of the MWE this should work.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[tabenum,1]{nosep,leftmargin=*,before=\begin{minipage}[t]{1.4\linewidth}, after =\end{minipage},}` in the preamble and `\begin{tabenum}\item....\end{tabenum}` in the second column of the table. For a list in the third column, you would need another customized list.